# Unterminated JSX contents, closing div tag gives error for no reason

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I was developing a react project and I was making a form and I ran into an error that I didn't know what was causing it

The Error:

```
Unterminated JSX contents (25:10)

  23 |       </a>
  24 |     <form />
> 25 |     </div>
     |           ^
  26 |   );
  27 | }
  28 |
```

My Code:

```
import React, { Component} from "react";

let Form = () => {
  return (
    <div className="log">
      <h2>Login</h2>
    
    <form>
      <div className="user-box">
        <input type="text" required="" />
        <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div className="user-box">
        <input type="password" required="" />
        <label>Password</label>
      <div />
      <a href="#">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        Submit
      </a>
    <form />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

I tried to remove the parent div but it throwed me an error so I added them back
I also looked up on some another questions but all I got was missing `/`

Kindly Help

Comment: its. a typo, you haven't closed the div correctly before a tag. <div /> should be </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I got it to work after doing a bit of researchon the difference between `<div/>` and `</div>`

`<div/>` would be for a single tag or something like `<input />` and `<image />`

So I changed all of the `<div/>` to the proper one

Code now:

```
import React, { Component} from "react";

let Form = () => {
  return (
    <div className="log">
      <h2>Login</h2>
    
      <form>
        <div className="user-box">
          <input type="text" required="" />
          <label>Username</label>
        </div>
        <div className="user-box">
          <input type="password" required="" />
          <label>Password</label>
          </div>
        <a href="#">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          Submit
        </a>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to fix your div closing tag.

```
  <div className="user-box">
            <input type="password" required="" />
            <label>Password</label>
  **<div />**
```

Comment: Sorry but It didn't work if you are changing the code kindly give me the full code

Comment: Saad,
Make sure your div tags are closed like this, </div> and your form tag is closed like this </form>

Answer (score 1):

In react you need to wrap multiple component with a parent component, using `<div/>` means you are closing the component in the same line and thus it's throws an error because components are not wrapped by parent div you should be using `<div> ....</div>`

Comment: Yes I also tried removing the parent or the div but it throwed me an error as you said.
Thanks